# Get link(s) that are NOT from 'example.com'

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
&#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Leon91"> /u/Leon91 </a> <br/> <span><a href="https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7646171/Jared-Kushner-greenlit-arrest-Jamal-Khashoggi-phone-call-Saudi-Prince.html">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/drfnas/jared_kushner_greenlit_arrest_of_jamal_khashoggi/">[comments]</a></span>
```

I would like to get all links that are NOT from `reddit.com`, such as a result that link `https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7646171/Jared-Kushner-greenlit-arrest-Jamal-Khashoggi-phone-call-Saudi-Prince.html`.

I tried the following, which matches ALL urls:

`(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})`

However, I would like to have all urls that are NOT from reddit.com.

Any suggestions how to approach this?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Use a negative lookaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all *`'a'`* tag href links using regex that doesn't contain *`reddit.com`* can be done like this :

The link is captured in group 2.

`<a(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])((?:(?!\1|reddit\.com)[\S\s])+)\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://regex101.com/r/UxKB0a/1